# 403 Forbidden - You don't have permission to access

Tags: php, laravel, apache, centos

I was getting too long URI problem and I did following on httpd.conf

```
LimitRequestLine 100000000
```

My URI is extremely long and its GET URI. After doing the above changes now I am getting

```
403 Forbidden
```

Comment: URI length limits often lie at the browser level as well. If you're running into these kinds of URI limitations, you may want to consider using some form of POST request instead. You should probably consider including additional information about what you're trying to accomplish so that you can receive advice about how to better circumvent this limitation.

Comment: The problem is I have to provide GET REST endpoint to third party system and they make GET request to my endpoint. They append all the job ID to a single URL and make GET request to me.

Comment: `In theory it should be unlimited, However in practice, most of the HTTP Clients or Browsers are limited to 2083 characters of Url Length. No one would use such type of URLs.` from [here](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/pqpFyXmjrx4/PJQ9IwA4BQAJ).

Comment: That's an incredibly stupid way for them to do things. I would encourage you to discuss this problem with the third party and make them aware of the URL length limitations. This isn't a limitation that can be easily avoided. They will either need to break their requests into multiple separate requests, or they will need to use a POST endpoint to avoid the limitation. This is a limitation with the tech itself, so you're not really at fault for not being able to handle it easily. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

Comment: @webDev Do you have access to the apache error log?

Comment: Yes and the error is `You don't have permission to access`